# Contenedor Docker Ubuntu 18.04 + Apache + PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker, contenedores

¡Buenas!

Tengo una duda sobre creación de imágenes y es debido a que al crear una con la instalación de Apache + PHP en Ubuntu, me encuentro con que en el proceso de instalación de PHP me pide interacción por mi parte. Para las interacciones que son de yes/no, no hay problema pongo un -y y ya esta.
Pero con PHP concretamente me pide una interacción de elegir un número para seleccionar mi zona geográfica.

¿En este caso que parámetro le tendría que pasar al comando de instalación?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por qué no usas una imagen ya creada como la oficial: <https://hub.docker.com/_/php/> Si necesitas personalizarla puedes echar un vistazo a como lo han hecho ellos en alguno de sus _Dockerfiles_. Por ejemplo [este](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c77c579341cfbfee90e669535ea3057679a1005b/7.3-rc/stretch/apache/Dockerfile) es el usado para tener apache+php.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Se que hay imágenes ya creadas con Apache y PHP pero era por saber si había alguna manera de automatizar ese tipo de instalaciones en las que te pide algo de interacción.
En este caso solo te pide que pongas un número con la localización, pero habrá otros que te pida introducir varios parámetros como usuarios y password y era por saber si se podía meter con alguna variable o con algún atributo del comando de instalación.
Actualmente estoy cacharreando y quería hacer por mi mismo todo lo que fuese posible sin tirar muchos de las imágenes ya hechas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el Dockerfile indicale en que timezone estas.

Asi evito que php me pregunte mi zona geografica:

```
ENV TZ="Europe/Madrid"
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```